# Неверное обозначение скобок в справке по Markdown

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, справка

[Отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#bare-urls):

> Четко указывайте URL-адреса, помещая их в квадратные скобки:

Вы видели `<http://example.com>`?

Это не квадратные скобки, а угловые. С квадратными выйдет так: [http://example.com].

Comment: В оригинале речь именно об угловых. Надо починить.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Спасибо, поправил в [соответствующей строке](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40264598?key=1a8ae41ef9612aa120e64e434f92e02b) на угловые скобки.

> Явно обозначайте URL-адреса, помещая их в угловые скобки:

Comment: Возможно, "URL-адрес" - не совсем корректное выражение. Если есть варианты получше - предлагайте.

Comment: Текст по ссылке не поменялся...